# Procedure As Argument - Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I am working with the following set of scheme definitions.  My question is specifically about the "tail" function.  What does the extra set of parentheses do that makes the function expect a procedure as an argument instead of a list, which would be the case with one set of parentheses?

```
(define (make-stream n f)
  (define (next m)
    (cons m (lambda () (next (f m)))))
  (next n))

(define head car)

(define (tail stream)
  ((cdr stream)))

(define (nth stream n)
  (if (= n 0) (head stream)
      (nth (tail stream) (- n 1))))

(define even (make-stream 0 (lambda (n) (+ n 2))))
```

Sorry if this is formatted incorrectly or is an otherwise inappropriate question, I'm trying to learn how to use this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is specifically about the "tail" function. What does the extra set of parentheses do that makes the function expect a procedure as an argument instead of a list, which would be the case with one set of parentheses?

Here's your procedure

```
(define (make-stream n f)
  (define (next m)
    (cons m (lambda () (next (f m)))))
  (next n))
```

Let's first look at what `car` and `cdr` would return

```
(car (make-stream 0 f) ; => 0
(cdr (make-stream 0 f) ; => (lambda () (next (f m)))
```

This nullary (zero-argument) procedure return by `car` is called a [Thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk). It's commonly used to delay evaluation of a computation. In this case, it's used to prevent `make-stream` from infinitely recursing as soon as `make-stream` is supplied its two arguments.

In order to get the next value out, all we have to do is apply the thunk. Note the extra parens this time

```
((cdr (make-stream 0 f))) ;=> (next (f m))
```

That's why you see ...

```
(define (tail stream) ((cdr stream)))
```

... which will return the next `cons`, instead of ...

```
(define (tail stream) (cdr stream))
```

... which would return a thunk containing the next `cons`

Answer (score 0):

In scheme, an expression use the first parameter of a s-expression as the method to evaluate with the following arguments.

For example:

```
(+ 1 2)
```

It is applying `+` to 1 and 2.

If we complicate our example a bit, we could do something like this.

```
(if (> x y) + -)
```

Here this expression will either return the `+` symbol or the `-`. We can transform that expression a bit further... with this:

```
((if (> x y) + -) 1 2)
```

Here the `if` expression will either return the `+` or `-` function that will later be applied with 1 and 2.

Now back to your method!

```
(define (tail stream)
  ((cdr stream)))
```

As you can see, you have double parenthesis. It means that it will apply the function located in the `cdr` of `stream`. Just as simple as that.

If we look at your constructor for stream, we can see that your constructor is actually returning a pair with a lambda function as the second member.

The second argument of `make-stream` is a function that is called to generate the next number. The method `f` doesn't have to be passed with each `next` call because it's available in the scope.